# Which music platforms are commonly used in China to listen or/and buy Chinese songs?

Tags: asian

I've been searching for a website where I can get a glimpse of the original quality of the song *Shi Wo Zai Zuo Duo Qing Zhong* (是我在做多情种) by *Hu Yang Lin* (胡杨林). After several hours of searching for the best quality, the best quality was this one: http://mp3en.co/download/s-33697374/shi-wo-zai-zuo-duo-qing-zhong-hu-yang-lin

Unfortunately, the quality is still not quite satisfying. I don't know if the original quality was supposed to be like that since I don't know how it is. Normally, you could simply compare the quality from iTunes, Spotify, Deezer and probably also on more platforms. But this time, I couldn't find the song from *Hu Yang Lin* on these platforms.

Is there a similar official music platform which is commonly used in China for Chinese music? With "official" I mean that the platforms are using the original song quality. Hence, the quality should be the best available.

After some research in this area, famous music platforms in China are QQ Music, Baidu and Xiami Music (the latter one isn't available in my country, though). But to me, they don't seem to be the official/legal platforms I'm searching for.